# Запятая при "к тому же"

Tags: пунктуация

Может ли "к тому же" являться вводным словом?

Во многих справочниках написан ряд слов, которые не отделяются запятой, в числе которых "к тому же". Но я встречала в книгах, где оно выделяется. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К тому же - это союз, поэтому запятая нужна.

Присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся **союзом «к тому же», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. После слов «к тому же» запятая не ставится.**

> Меж тем регулировщица, став перед полуторкой, ругала Хижняка, несомненного виновника затора, **к тому же не желавшего осаживать назад,** за обочину, на арестную площадку, как она требовала. В. Богомолов, Момент истины. Правда, у нас читают редко Евангелие, **к тому же народ наш темный,** неграмотный…. М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. К тому же каждый день шел снег, и каждое утро приходилось, прежде чем приступить к самой работе, порядочно поработать лопатой. М. Пришвин, Серая Сова.

@ Обороты со словами «и к тому же» обычно не обособляются.

> Не ябедничать же на Зефирку, тварь бессловесную **и к тому же,** как выяснилось, нескверную сердцем. Б. Акунин, Внеклассное чтение. Слегка, приятно опьянев **и ободренный к тому же** Зосиной приветливостью, я начал поглядывать на нее чуть длительнее... В. Богомолов, Зося.

[См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Грамота.ру.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_384)